# How to fix WordPress Fatal Error Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: php, wordpress, typeerror, fatal-error, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi I have a WordPress Site that is currently not letting me access the dashboard.

I have reinstalled the core, updated Plugins through cPanel. I turned off the plugins, and it still won't work. I have turned on debuging and this is what it says.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "wpse242371_remove_editor_from_some_pages" not found or invalid function name 
in /home/comhairleadmin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308 
Stack trace:
 #0 /home/comhairleadmin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
 #1 /home/comhairleadmin/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
 #2 /home/comhairleadmin/public_html/wp-admin/admin-header.php(118): do_action('admin_enqueue_s...', 'index.php')
 #3 /home/comhairleadmin/public_html/wp-admin/index.php(137): require_once('/home/comhairle...')
 #4 {main} thrown in /home/comhairleadmin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 308
```

I am not sure how to fix this. Or how to go about fixing this.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: There very specific function can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/242371/12496), so maybe trying adding that to your theme temporarily.

Comment: I am using php 8.2

Comment: I'll try adding that in and hope that works.

Comment: WordPress core isn't yet fully compatible with php 8.2 as of version 6.2. Still some deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere some code called

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts',
           'wpse242371_remove_editor_from_some_page');
```

or something similar, but no such callback function exists. It you're working with a new-to-you plugin, look at the code where it configures its admin (dashboard) page.